# Can PySide be used with Anaconda Python 3.5?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, anaconda, python-3.5

There seems to be very little information out there about PySide/PySide2 support under Anaconda 4.2 Python 3.5. While Anaconda 4.2 officially supports PyQt5 for both Python2.7 and Python3.5, PySide can be installed with PyQt4 support under Python2.7 using `conda install pyside`.

Has anyone had experience getting PySide2 with Qt5 working with Python 3.5 under Anaconda?

Is the problem just in the general maturity of PySide2? It is important to have an LGPL licence for Qt under Python3 but I would like to stick with using Anaconda/Miniconda.

Comment: Do you need PySide1(Qt4 binding)? here is a unofficial 32bit build for Python3.5: https://github.com/krrr/PySide/releases

Comment: Thanks. At the very least I need PySide1 64-bit on Linux but since Anaconda 4 comes with PyQt5 by default I thought that Qt4 would be a headache to set up.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just use:

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda install pyside2
```

Use PySide for QT4 and PySide2 for QT5.
You will find a QT Designer under Anaconda/Library/bin/

Answer (score 0):

With Anaconda3, I had to install using pip instead:

```
pip install pyside2
```